# Program that finds the number you are thinking doesn't work properly, what is wrong?

Tags: c++

Im having trouble with this recursion code. Basically I want the computer to "guess" in as little steps as possible the number that I am thinking of. However, everything works except the final output. The bounds are fine, and it narrows down the guess until it asks me if the number im thinking of is say 16, if I input "=" it should output 16 instead it always outputs 50. Could anyone help me locate the error?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned int search (unsigned int boundInf, unsigned int boundSup);

int main ()
{
    int b;
    b = search (1, 100);

    cout << "Your number must be : " << b << endl;
}

unsigned int search (unsigned int boundInf, unsigned int boundSup)
{
    string magnitude;
    int b;
    b = (boundSup + boundInf) / 2;
    
    cout << "Is your number <, > or = to " << b << "? ";
    cin >> magnitude;

    if (magnitude == "<") {
        cout << "Between " << boundInf << " and " << b << endl;
        search (boundInf, b);
    }
    else if (magnitude == ">") {
        cout << "Between " << b << " and " << boundSup << endl;
        search (b, boundSup);
    }
    
    return b;
}
```

Comment: You don't `return search(boundInf, b);` and `return search(b, boundSup);` (or `b =  search(boundInf, b);` and `b = search(b, boundSup);`) so the function will always return the `b` you calculated in the first call. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If you don't store the value returned from function calls, it disappears.

Comment: Your code takes too long, so I came up with a new number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to change the value of `b` when going deeper into the recursive function, this can be easily fixed by changing the `search` function like so:

```
unsigned int search(unsigned int boundInf, unsigned int boundSup)
{
    string magnitude;
    int b;
    b = (boundSup + boundInf) / 2;
    cout << "Is your number <, > or = to " << b << "? ";
    cin >> magnitude;

    if (magnitude == "<")
    {
        cout << "Between " << boundInf << " and " << b << endl;
        b = search(boundInf, b);
    }
    else if (magnitude == ">")
    {
        cout << "Between " << b << " and " << boundSup << endl;
        b = search(b, boundSup);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, now when I run the program it still continues to repeat even after it guessed the number and I inputed "=", how can I add a way to break out of the loop?

Comment: I only changed what I showed above and the program exits correctly so, maybe you changed something more, if you could share your current code, I'm more than happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just added another else if clause for when I input "=" and it exits properly, thank you so much!